# How do I get the window size in css?

Tags: css, html, header

I am currently writing my header for my website, and I have a friend who is helping me. We have two very different computers (PC and Mac) and used different browsers to ensure that it is multiplatform and everything, and we found that the header doesn't fit on his screen. So I realized it would be easier to just get the windows width and divide that by four and make that the size of the buttons. How would I going about doing this?

Thanks so much!

EDIT:
Here is what I am using:

```
    div.horizontal
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:45px;
}   

div.horizontal ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
} 

div.horizontal li
{
float:left;
}

div.horizontal a
{
display:block;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.10) 52%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url("../img/truefactzheader.png");
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(52%,rgba(255,255,255,0.10)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))), url("../img/truefactzheader.png");
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.10) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url("../img/truefactzheader.png");
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.10) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url("../img/truefactzheader.png");
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.10) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url("../img/truefactzheader.png");
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.10) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url("../img/truefactzheader.png");
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 );
width:25%;
height:35px;
}

div.horizontal a:link,div.horizontal a:visited
{
font-weight:bold;
color:#FFFFFF;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

div.horizontal a:hover,div.horizontal a:active
{
height:45px;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 100%), url("../img/truefactzheader.png");
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25))), url("../img/truefactzheader.png");
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 100%), url("../img/truefactzheader.png");
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 100%), url("../img/truefactzheader.png");
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 100%), url("../img/truefactzheader.png");
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 100%), url("../img/truefactzheader.png");
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#99000000', endColorstr='#99000000',GradientType=0 );
a:link {text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
}
```

Comment: This is the wrong way to approach the question. General solutions: 1) Combine CSS properties like `width:25%; min-width:100px;` on the buttons to make them size dynamically, 2) use [CSS3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to apply different styles depending on the screen width (e.g., make the buttons stack vertically on a small screen), or 3) use JavaScript to do the same thing as #2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, assuming that your header element is 100% width of the screen, and you want the buttons to be equal width, the maths should be > 100 / 4 = 25%. Each of your buttons should occupy 25% of the header's width.

So, in your CSS you should define them as follows:

```
#my_header {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
    #my_header a.button {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 25%;
        height: 30px
    }
```

Please see this [**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d36RH/).

So, you need to update your code as follows (I've taken out the browser-specific properties for clarity:

```
div.horizontal {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:45px;
}   

div.horizontal ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} 
div.horizontal li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

div.horizontal a {
    display: block;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.10) 52%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%), url("../img/truefactzheader.png");
    height:35px;
}
```

Comment: Might want to add `overflow:hidden;` on 'a.button`. +1

Comment: Or you could add the `text-overflow` property. Plenty of scope here for improvement, I agree :) Should give the OP a good boilerplate to work from, mind you. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `inline-block` in this case is a better option than a `float`.

Comment: Could be. Depends if he has other elements in the header that might conflict.

Comment: Updated w/ code. None of the proposed answers have worked yet!

Comment: Of course they don't work. You're giving the `a` elements a width of 25% relative to their parent, which in your case is the `li` element.

Comment: Oops! Sorry! I just learnt CSS two days ago and didn't realize there was inheritance!

Comment: No problem. I have updated the answer to include the correct code your application.